# Problem with CRS metadata for UK Environment Agency LiDAR DSM tiles?

Tags: qgis, dem, lidar, metadata, ordnance-survey

I have downloaded some LIDAR DSM composite tiles from 
https://environment.data.gov.uk/DefraDataDownload/?Mode=survey
and opened them in QGIS 3.6 with project CRS set to OSGB 1936 (EPSG:27700).

However, the tiles are floating off the coast of West Africa, when I check the metadata for 'extent' there is none. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: If you right click on the layer in the layers panel and set its CRS to EPSG:27700 does it then plot in the right place?

Comment: check you have used 27700 not 2770 as you have typed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input. The issue appears to be due to attempting to an ESRI basemap which doesn't work with the dataset even with the CRS set to the OS 27700 described in the question? Using open street map has sorted this. I'm new to QGIS so don't understand why the ESRI map doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't get your issue in QGIS 3.6

Here is the 25CM DSM in the correct location (SW Reading)

**Using OSGB EPGS 27700**
http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/osgb-1936-british-national-grid/html/

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I figured you were using open street map from the screenshot and tried this which worked.

Answer (score 1):

EA DEMs do not contain CRS data, thus they will load using the QGIS default CRS, which out-of-the box is EPSG:4326.

To change this go Settings -> Options and click on CRS in the list on the left. Here you can set the default CRS for new projects and the default CRS for new layers. Set both to EPSG:27700, which should cure your problem.

[image]